# Can companies that hired for remote positions decide to go back to office?

Tags: united-states, telecommute, remote-work, exempt

With the pandemic, I've seen tons of vacancies from many Fortune 500 companies where the vacancy specifically says that the position will be permanently 100% remote (i.e.. they *never* have to go to the office).

I assume that many people applied to these positions (and were hired) because of this specific benefit. I also assume that many people quit their current jobs to apply for these 100% remote jobs.

Can these companies suddenly decide that the job will no longer be remote? If so, what would happen to the people that are unable to go to the office?

An extreme example: someone in California working 100% remote for a company in Florida.

I'm not asking for myself, although these remote positions are tempting.

I ask because there are thousands of people that applied (and were hired) to these positions and most assume that nothing can change.

Comment: I know people that live in a state and were hired for a remote position at another state.

Comment: This reads highly hypothetical IMO

Comment: @DarkCygnus Even if it is hypothetical, it's a question that people can still find useful. For example, those considering fully remote jobs now know to get that location specified in their contract.

Comment: Depends entirely on the legal details of the contract and employment laws.  I'd be surprised if *any* properly drawn-up contract said remote working was permanent and irrevocable.  It's unlikely a company would tie their own hands up in such a way.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie usually hypothetical Qs are discouraged, because they are harder to answer correctly and precisely, OP is unable to clarify or enhance (as its not real, it's hypothetical), etc... besides this one is also near "company-specific" and "depends on locale" territory (another thing that makes it hard to answer in a canonical or helpful way for everybody)...  although to be honest I see that currently this has not derailed and answer are ok, so :)

Comment: @GregoryCurrie some reading: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/is-a-question-being-hypothetical-a-problem , (old answer) https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2131/73791 , (and to balance things out) https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7017/73791

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'm aware of the debate around this. I don't have a problem with hypothetical provided they are firmly in the realm of possibility. (There is certainly no consensus around this). This situation does not seem outlandish at all to me, especially as there would be a lot of employees hired with "remote positions" during COVID, and as the situation improves may be asked to work from the office. I note that there are many good answers here.

Comment: Just further to my point, when I answer questions, I'm trying to think about how the question can be useful to other people in the future, along with the OP. For a purely hypothetical question, it's easy for me to just focus on the "other people".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can these companies suddenly decide that the job will no longer be remote? If so, what would happen to the people that are unable to go to the office?

If the employee's contract states that the job is 100% remote, then this would be a change to the agreed contract. Whether the employer can unilaterally decide to change the terms of the contract and enforce them on the employee will depend on both the wording of the contract and the laws in the relevant country/state.

In places that have strong rights for workers this would not be possible, and attempting to fire someone for not agreeing to this change would be constructive dismissal, just like it would be unacceptable to decide to cut an employee's pay in half and then fire them unless they agree.

But you need to look up the laws in the relevant area, or (better yet) speak to a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying that this type of detail should be mentioned in the contract that the employee signs?

Comment: Long long before Covid, a company in the UK that I had left just about at the right time was sold, the new owner decided the wanted to close everything down, and in order to avoid redundancy payments, they moved the company 300 miles away, lots of people quit, and then they closed down.

Comment: @rbhat if the employee is effectively arguing "You agreed that I could work 100% so you have to continue to let me do that", they need to be able to evidence that agreement. That would *usually* be done by pointing to the relevant line in their contract, but doesn't have to be. They may also be able to point to something else in writing (such as an email), or even argue that it was part of a verbal contract - but those are harder to argue, and may not hold up in some countries.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think this is again in the contract https://www.gov.uk/employer-relocation-your-rights . As I understand it, they would need to have that mobility clause in there. Do I know if any of my jobs had mobility clauses in their contracts? No idea :-)

Comment: I can see a company successfully arguing that they will no longer support remote positions, therefore making the remote position no longer exist, and having the onsite position be an offer for a new position that the employee can either accept or reject (or something roughly to that effect). That argument wouldn't work for cutting someone's salary in half. But whether this argument would work would depend entirely on local laws in the applicable area (although I can't imagine that a company can legally be forced to continue supporting remote work indefinitely in any sensible legal system).

Comment: I agree with @gnasher729. In Europe transfer requires a compensation, but it is still possible. But I saw many cases where the company was willing to pay a big severance payment to close a site, so I think that a company deciding to terminate remote work and handle it as a location transfer is possible even if it has a cost.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I think you're spot on. "Remote work" seems like part of a job title now, rather than just a mere property of the employment, and it implies a certain style of working.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Why would a company be allowed to unilaterally change a contract just because they don't like it anymore? If they signed a contract that says the employee can work 100% remote they can try to negotiate with the employee but I don't see how any sensible legal system should allow them to just change that part of the contract at will.

Comment: @quarague A company may be allowed to "unilaterally change a contract" here for the same reason they may be allowed to "unilaterally change a contract" by shutting down a branch or department. If you're going to handcuff companies by preventing that, you're probably going to unnecessarily force a whole lot of them into bankruptcy, and many others with probably just find some legal loopholes. The company just needs to be able to make a good case that it's non-trivial/not free to continue supporting remote work, and they need to be consistent in who they're applying the change to.

Comment: @mattfreake I think what they did was just a numbers game. They must have had 50 employees at the time. If twenty say "Ok, I move", and twenty say "I'll quit", and ten say "this is illegal, you can't do that", then instead of 50 redundancy packages they would pay 30. Lots of money saved.

Answer (score 5):

> Can these companies suddenly decide that the job will no longer be
> remote?

I would say that in the USA the answer would be yes, unless there's a legal contract or law that prohibits it.

> If so, what would happen to the people that are unable to go to the
> office?

I would say that in the USA the answer would be that they could terminate your employment, unless there's a legal contract or law that prohibits it.

Comment: I know many people that quit their current jobs and applied to these positions because they would be permanently remote (according to the vacancy post). Isn't there anything that protects them?

Comment: @rbhat Is the remote job permanent or can the employer terminate the job whenever they wish to?

Comment: The remote job is permanent, like any other job. The difference is that it's remote.

Comment: @rbhat since most US companies can get rid of you for no reason at all, why would there be anything to protect you from them changing their mind about remote?  The only thing that protects you is your value to them - if you are a worker they very much want to keep, and you're only willing to work remote, then your value is your protection.

Comment: @rbhat What would protect them is any agreements or contracts that they sign. About 3/4 of US employees can be fired for (effectively) any reason whatsoever, including refusing to come into the office to work.

Comment: Most states in the USA are at-will states, which means your employer can terminate your employment for any reason or no reason, so long as the reason isn't legally prohibited by contract or by law. So... I would think that no, there's nothing to protect you in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the examples in the question, I'll assume that this is taking place in the US.

> Can these companies suddenly decide that the job will no longer be
> remote?

Yes, they can.

> If so, what would happen to the people that are unable to go to the
> office?

They would likely have to find a new job, unless they have a union contract or other contract that gives them special rights. (That would be unusual).

> I ask because there are thousands of people that applied (and were
> hired) to these positions and most assume that nothing can change.

I'm not sure most assume nothing can change. If they did make that assumption, they made a mistake.

Comment: Just a bit of a footnote that about 1/4 of US workers are not strictly at-will due to enterprise bargaining agreements, or other forms of contracts.

Answer (score 0):

In Canada, the employer would typically have to pay severance if the employee chooses not to make the change voluntarily. The amount of severance can be determined by the employment contract, by a collective bargaining agreement, by the Provincial Employment Standards Act or (which can be much more expensive in some cases) by common law.

Even if the employee is being asked to cross the street daily from their condo to the office building, rather than (say) moving from Halifax to Toronto, that small-ish change can be arguably interpreted as 'constructive dismissal'.

That's from my experience, not to be taken as legal advice.